# How to loop constant e by the infinite series

Tags: c, for-loop

> The value for  is given by the infinite series
>     =  +/!+/!+/!+/!+ ⋯
>   The above algorithm is computationally effective. Use it to compute  to an
>   arbitrary precision.

How to type the formula into code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double e;
    double n;
    float i;
    n = atof(argv[1]);
    e = 1;
    for (I = 0; I < n; i++)
    e = 1 + 1/n!;
    printf("%.10f\n", e);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial

Comment: You seem to have two problems. One is to confuse the `!` operator with the faculty. The other is a very basic lack of understanding cumulative operations in a loop. I am afraid that you need to go back a few steps and learn e.g. how to add up all numbers from 1...1000. Handling those two problems would be too much, i.e. too broad for an answer. Consider asking how to calculate a faculty first, but check that the question has not been asked already, compare the comment by Ry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, because you are taking each factorial sequentially, you don't need to calculate it each time; you can just use the previous value and multiply by the current number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double e = 1.0, f = 1.0; // f is your 'accumulated' factorial
    int i, n = atoi(argv[1]); // Best to use integers for loop counting
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        f *= i; // First time, this wil be 1 * 1 = 1; second time 2, third 6, etc
        e += 1.0/f; // Divide here by our 'running' value for i!
    }
    printf("%.10f\n", e);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate factorial.you can use

```
 long long factorial(int n){
    long long fact=1;
    for(i=2;i<=;i++)
     fact*=1;
     return fact;
    }
```

and for cumulative sum you should use e=e+ 1+1/n!
you can calculate n! using above factorial function.Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Since it is easy for the `factorial` function to overflow, this should be checked. An `exception` should be thrown if `n` is too large. -CW